# Stop workbook from running 'cancelled' Timed code

Tags: vba, excel

Edit: I've managed to solve the problem below by using `Application.EnableEvents = False` in Workbook A to stop the `Workbook_Open()` code from running in Workbook B but am still stumped by the problem if anybody care to explain?

I've got Workbook A opening, editing, saving and closing Workbook B. As Workbook B is used by multiple users, I made it switch to Read-Only mode upon opening and display a pop-up message. However, when running the code from Workbook A, I want to stop the message box from opening. I used `Application.OnTime` to change Workbook B to Read-Only upon opening and to cancel the pending code upon saving within 10 seconds.

Problem: The code works when I open Workbook B directly and save within 10 seconds but when running a code from Workbook A to `open=>edit=>save=>close Workbook B`, Workbook B will open by itself even after it is closed.

After doing much research and trial and error by trying to use Public variables and Referencing VBA project, I settled on `Application.OnTime` using the resource below:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/OnTime.aspx

Below is a sample of my code.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

Call StopTimer

End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Call StartTimer

End Sub



Public RunWhen As Double
Public Const cRunWhat = "Change_File_Access"
Public Const cRunIntervalSeconds = 15
Public DatabaseWB As Workbook

Sub StartTimer()

RunWhen = Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, cRunIntervalSeconds)
Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=RunWhen, Procedure:=cRunWhat, _
    Schedule:=True

End Sub

Sub StopTimer()

MsgBox RunWhen
On Error Resume Next
Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=RunWhen, Procedure:=cRunWhat, _
    Schedule:=False

End Sub

Sub Change_File_Access()

If Not Workbooks("WorkbookB.xlsm").ReadOnly Then Workbooks("WorkbookB.xlsm").ChangeFileAccess xlReadOnly
MsgBox "This file is set as Read-Only"

End Sub
```

Comment: Just to make sure I understand correctly, the code in Workbook A executes as expected, but the Workbook B reopens 15 seconds after you initially opened it?

Answer (score 0):

Some quick testing shows the timer seems to be running within the context of the Workbook that the macro resides in - not the Workbook that you executed it from. So, you need to do one of 2 things - either quit the Excel application completely (probably not convenient) or reset the timer from the Worksheet you're running the code from.

I.e., in WorkbookA:

```
Dim book As Workbook

Set book = Workbooks.Open("WorkbookB.xlsm")
book.Save
Application.Run book.Name & "!StopTimer"
book.Close
```